# What's a good robust way to query processes for their help or framework origin especially in Windows?

Tags: windows, frameworks, observer-pattern, process, query

What's a good robust way to query processes for their help or framework origin, especially in Windows?

I've got an automated testing module that queries binaries that fit a special name pattern with `--help` to see what test framework, if any, was used to compile that test binary, so it can give it special command treatment depending on the test mode's objective.

The problem is that since it won't be only used by me, I anticipate that binaries that require manual interaction before they quit will be triggered for Murphy's law and subsequently fail to exit on their own.

I'd prefer my module to be robust enough to handle this scenario, so I thought about launching that process within another process, getting its PID, and setting up some kind of observer pattern to meaningfully monitor it over time or events triggered, whichever first.

I anticipate no problems with that, which worries me :) I feel like I'm missing an important currently nebulous corner-case. I also wonder if there's a better way to check binaries for their framework origins used than doing `--help` queries to search for framework help message output patterns.

I'd really like to skip the whole, running binaries blindly to figure out what kind of test binary they are, step, but I don't know if I can do this reliably, dynamically, in a generic approach.

So,

1. Can a binary's origin, if created within a framework, be somehow detected in a non-framework-specific way besides a help query? That includes common approaches that aren't necessarily universally embraced, or common approaches doled out by each framework in an easy way; meaning, I could make a handful of small modules for supported frameworks that are known. ***(answered in comments)***
2. If I use a dedicated process to check the status of a process that I've launched, can I safely handle all spawned process responses? Crashes, unresponsiveness, etc, stuff like that. For example, if a missing DLL triggering an error-pop-up even when launched from command-line.

Comment: How about just kill the process after 5 seconds?

Comment: Are os-level `kill` / `taskkill` commands guaranteed to nuke the process regardless of its state? If so, that would be a viable approach for #2.

Comment: Can't you just check which dependencies the binaries have? See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency, the second answer from the top, suggesting `dumpbin /dependents`?

Comment: Huzzah, @DocBrown! Big win using that guy ^_^ Perfect for finding out what framework binaries came from, if applicable. `dumpbin /dependents file.ext | call findstr /i framework_dependency_dll_name` then `if "%errorlevel%"=="0"` for match verification. <3 it. That works perfectly with the rest of my batches.

Comment: Darn. It only comes with installations of Visual Studio, and this app doesn't distribute with that let alone assume it's going to be installed. I'm sure I can find a way to get the same similar behavior from my own command-line tool if I whip something up with native OS libraries. I'll try C++ first...

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: `dumpbin /dependents dumpbin.exe` shows it is just linked against the usual Visual C++ Redistributable libraries, I don't think you need to install a full Visual for this. The usual VC++ runtime packages should be suffcient, download here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Thanks, @DocBrown; I'll spin up a VM and check it out; that would be a relief! Looking around for c++ solutions for this problem has been surprisingly lacking; I was in the middle of checking out `LoadLibraryEx` but didn't have a working sample, yet.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I misunderstood you. The issue is not the ability to run, but the legality of redistributing Microsoft binaries. I'm not actually allowed to just copy `dumpbin` and `link` and package it with my software per what's allowed by Visual Studio ( 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/2015-redistribution-vs ) unless I misunderstood that page.

Comment: I was trying to keep my command-line tools as close to standard library C/C++ for fast performance and if required native OS libraries, but this might a case where a more appropriate step is to actually leverage .NET; the *nix version of this can just use `ldd` and not even require a standalone tool to be created. I think the best thing to unblock #1 for now is to whip up something with .NET, and I can always circle back to give another shot at `LoadLibraryEx`.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: well, you did not tell us so far what kind of license requirements you have. But if this is for a program you want to distribute to a third party, you are probably correct, I guess Microsoft does not seem to allow the distribution. If Google does not help, maybe you can ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if there is a similar tool with different license terms.

Comment: ... another alternative is Dependency walker, which is free and has a command like mode, see http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: .NET ended up being a wash for inspecting non-.NET binaries with `System.BadImageFormatException: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.` , but not too surprising there. On to `LoadLibraryEx` ! ^_^ As soon as my corrupted VS installation finishes repairing sometime before the current linux epoch expires...

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, everyone! This was a fun journey! ^_^ I'm seeing just how useless the static import table _could_ be depending on how it's built using tools like `cl.exe` directly; however for the goal of detecting test frameworks, so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

OP here, an update addressing the question:

1. You *can* detect *some* dependencies for *some* test frameworks, depending on how the binary was *built* and *linked* to. The *only* information you *can* get from the binary without loading and exercising it is this thing called the `Import Table`, aka Static Import Table, not to be confused with the Import Address Table, which changes once the image loads. You're not going to get the DLLs loaded by the process via Win32 APIs like `LoadProcess`, so mileage will vary.

For example, if I build my tool with just calling the VCVARS batch and running `cl.exe source.cpp /EHsc`, it's going to give me very different dependency information than if I say, make the same exact Visual C++ Empty Project that incorporates all the helper configurations from `projName.vcxproj`

For .NET assemblies, I made a lean-and-mean console-app to detect .NET Assemblies used for .NET test frameworks. It's source is available to view on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669672/3543437

2. Not all corner-cases can be guaranteed but most can be *overcome* when you both have admin privs and use `taskkill` to the process tree by process ID. I've found doing system calls like `taskkill /F /T /PID %PID%`and checking its error code is a perfectly suitable replacement for a programmatic way to nuke a process not responding desirably

To achieve my overall goal for this question, I made two C++ modules;

The first was a command-line utility to parse and read off the PE COFF Import Table's dependency names, like `dumpbin` and `link` can do, using error codes to help determine if there were dependencies or not, so tools like `findstr` can be leveraged. I'm looking forward to using `ldd` instead of porting this sucker... it was a long and painful process due to how low-level and obscure it was. I basically had to re-learn low-level memory management, so that was actually a good thing.

The second was a command-line utility that took a process name/location, one argument for how long it could last for in milliseconds, and one for how often to poll it in milliseconds; then an additional optional argument to take a double-quote surrounded list of parameters. The kill-timer is absolute, but I coded it so exit-codes let you know how the process ended. All by checking exit codes, it lets you know if:
* Process exited on its own, non-zero
* Process exited on its on, zero
* Process had to be force-killed
* Process failed to launch
* User queried the help

Which covers all the cases I could think of at the time.

Overall this process took a lot longer than expected, due to dealing with the PE COFF stuff. If you find yourself in similar shoes, see if you can find an open source project that uses a stack that plays well with yours.

I also found the following resources really helpful when trying to understand the PE COFF:

A. [Visualization of the PECOFF File Format](http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/files/reference/PE%20Format.pdf) 
B. [X86 Dissassembly Breakdown](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files) 
C. [Executable File Analysis (Windows Forensic Analysis) Part 2](http://what-when-how.com/windows-forensic-analysis/executable-file-analysis-windows-forensic-analysis-part-2/)

Honorable mention that might cause you headaches due to being dated:

D. [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) by Matt Pietrek, March 1994, Microsoft Systems Journal